# Jasper Reports - HTML5 Reports(highcharts) - String Replace for Labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jasper-reports

Hoping someone can help. Trying to do a string replace on the labels for my bar chart. So this is built on jasper studio and is a html5 report.

Trying to add the replace function as a javascript function in the report "Advanced Properties". Previously I have successfully set a function here for xAxis.labels.formatter to append labels,

"function(){return this.value.toString().substring(0,5)}"

I have tried to update this for string replace and came up with the below:

"function(){return this.value.toString().str.replace("Section7","W3Schools")}"

This is not working.I dont have much javascript experience and I have tried different formats of the above but no luck so far, any suggestions would be much appreciated?

Comment: Sorry, "Section 7" would be my current label and wnat to replace it with "W3Schools"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. The replace function, works with the below:

1. Set property name as:

   `xAxis.labels.formatter`
2. Use as expression:

   `true`

3.Property Value:

`"function(){return this.value.replace(\"Section 7\",\"W3Schools\")}"`

Or

```
<hc:chartProperty name="xAxis.labels.formatter">
                        <hc:propertyExpression><![CDATA["function(){return this.value.replace(\"Section 7\",\"W3Schools\")}"]]></hc:propertyExpression>
                    </hc:chartProperty>
```